# Extract max-sum submatrices

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I've a `2D` `NxN` matrix that has elements from a set of real numbers. I need to identify top `n` `DxD` sub-matrices from it such that their sum is maximum and return top left index of the sub-matrices. I need to do it in Tensorflow.

For example I have following `4x4` matrix:

```
[1 1 4 4]
[1 1 4 4]
[3 3 2 2]
[3 3 2 2]
```

I need to identify 2 sub-matrices that have the largest sum and return their top left index. In above case, 2 sub-matrices that have the largest and second largest sum are:

```
[[4 4]    [[3 3]
 [4 4]] &  [3 3]]
```

I need to return `[[0,2],[2,0]]`, the top left indices to both the matrices. Thanks.

Comment: I suppose you need to consider all possible submatrices, and not just non-overlapping ones, right? That is, in your example, `[[1, 4], [1, 4]]` and `[[1, 4], [3, 2]]` are valid submatrices, right?

Comment: Yes, all submatrices of size 2x2. They might overlap - pretty much like a sliding window operation in a convolution, I need to "see" all sub-matrices and find the top n sum-wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get that with the following snippet. The idea is to build a tensor holding the row and column indices of each element of each submatrix, then sum the submatrices and find the largest sums.

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Input data
input = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None])
# Submatrix dimension
dims = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [2])
# Number of top submatrices to find
k = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [])
# Sizes
input_shape = tf.shape(input)
rows, cols = input_shape[0], input_shape[1]
d_rows, d_cols = dims[0], dims[1]
subm_rows, subm_cols = rows - d_rows + 1, cols - d_cols + 1
# Index grids
ii, jj = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(subm_rows), tf.range(subm_cols), indexing='ij')
d_ii, d_jj = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(d_rows), tf.range(d_cols), indexing='ij')
# Add indices
subm_ii = ii[:, :, tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis] + d_ii
subm_jj = jj[:, :, tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis] + d_jj
# Make submatrices tensor
subm = tf.gather_nd(input, tf.stack([subm_ii, subm_jj], axis=-1))
# Add submatrices
subm_sum = tf.reduce_sum(subm, axis=(2, 3))
# Use TopK to find top submatrices
_, top_idx = tf.nn.top_k(tf.reshape(subm_sum, [-1]), tf.minimum(k, tf.size(subm_sum)))
# Get row and column
top_row = top_idx // subm_cols
top_col = top_idx % subm_cols
result = tf.stack([top_row, top_col], axis=-1)

# Test
with tf.Session() as sess:
    mat = [
        [1, 1, 4, 4],
        [1, 1, 4, 4],
        [3, 3, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 2, 2],
    ]
    print(sess.run(result, feed_dict={input: mat, dims: [2, 2], k: 2}))
```

Output:

```
[[0 2]
 [1 2]]
```

Note that the output in this case is `[0, 2]` and `[1, 2]`, but not `[2, 0]`. That's because the submatrix starting at `[1, 2]` sums the same amount as the one at `[2, 0]`, and it is before in the matrix, if you iterate it by rows. If you pass `k: 3` in the test you would get `[2, 0]` too in the result.

Comment: I was wondering if there's a way to use this piece of code in a trainable network? In other words, if I can pass 'result' to a loss function and do training. When I do this now, I get an error and I think it's because top_k is a non-differentiable function.

Comment: @Ahsan Yes, I think that is the case. However, it is not clear to me how you would actually differentiate this. The values in `result` are indices, so what should their derivative based on? You would take `tf.diff` on `input` (that is, consider `input` as evaluations of a continuous function)?